# 'fadeOut' in 'onbeforeunload' - JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I possible force the script to wait with the unload thing until the 'fadeOut' is done? I've tried several things but none of them seem to work, it just instantly redirects me to the specified URL.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        $(document).fadeOut(1500,function(){
            // do something here to confirm the redirect
        });
    };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to bypass this issue. I simply called a JQuery function on each element of type 'a', then I requested the fadeOut after making sure the 'href' attribute is indeed a valid URL path.

Comment: Why don't you make it redirect manually in the callback for the `fadeOut()`?

Comment: Because I do not know what the URL is, and there's no possible way for me to get it as far as I know.

Comment: You can't lookup the `href` attrs of the `a` tags? Like, just set the a's onclick to return false (I think that should work), then on the callback that fires later, read out the tag's `href` attribute.

Comment: Well that's what I eventually did, as described in my own answer. That wasn't my first goal though, I tried to make it work without using the 'click' event for my 'a' tag.

Comment: What if the location of the page is changed using `if(confirm("Do you want to view the content now?")){location.href="the_content.html";}`? Wouldn't you need `onbeforeunload` event to catch that?